# CentOS7: Restart multiple instances of a service with one command

Tags: systemd, centos-7

Is there a way of restarting all instances of a service in systemd using only one command?

Suppose we have two daemons running called thingd@01 and thingd@02. Can I restart just those without having to resort to making one call to systemctl per instance?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be able to restart both of them with one systemctl, just put a space between the services. E.g. `systemctl restart thingd@01 thingd@02`

I usually stop all major services before cloning an instance after it has been removed from a load balanced pool. I use the following:

*# stop php-fpm, MariaDB, nginx and postfix*

```
systemctl stop php-fpm nginx postfix mariadb
```

*# check status after they have been stopped*

```
systemctl status php-fpm nginx postfix mariadb
```

*# start all of them again*

```
systemctl start php-fpm nginx postfix mariadb
```

Comment: That works! also...
`systemctl restart thing@{1..8}`
seems to work with it.
Thank you @mstephenson.

Comment: @user1096824 if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: For stop or restart also possible `systemctl stop 'thing*'`. Also [systemd target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html) could be used to group multiple instances.